# React Native: Image not displaying with dynamic/local URI

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, react-native-image-picker

so I'm trying to display an Image with a dynamic uri/path (at initialization it displays a placeholder image, and then later changes) like so:

```
<Image source={this.state.pickedImage == null? require('./Placeholder.jpeg'):{uri: this.state.pickedImage}}/>
```

where `this.state.pickedImage` is initialized as `null`, and then changed using `react-native-image-picker`'s `launchCamera` and `launchImageLibrary` like below:

```
cameraHandler = () => {
    ImagePicker.launchCamera({title: "Pick an Image", maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 600}, res => {
        if (res.didCancel) {
            console.log("User cancelled!");
        } else if (res.error) {
            console.log("Error", res.error);
        } else {
            this.setState({
                pickedImage:  res.uri,
                imageSize: res.fileSize,
            });
        }
    });
}};
```

(I should mention that I've implemented `launchImageLibrary` in *exactly* the same way, so I didn't really see a reason to put it here.)

and while the placeholder image shows up just fine, whenever I upload a new image, the `<Image/>` doesn't seem to render at all and I'm only left with a background.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried doing something like initializing `this.state.pickedImage` in my `state` like:

```
pickedImage: require('./Placeholder.jpeg').uri
```

and then adding the image tag like:

```
<Image source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}} />
```

but alas that just ends up preventing me from rendering any images at all.

I've thought about dynamically binding the paths to `require()` like [here](https://dev.to/emilios1995/dynamic-imports-in-react-native-9k5) (and also many places on this site), but as I understand it, you need to know what the potential images you might want to be from beforehand, and if I'm using the camera, I can't really do that. (Also, it's not like I can set up a list and export every image on the user's phone from beforehand, so my hands are tied there.) (Apparently, there's no way to *really* dynamically bind to require() the way I'm looking for, [because the package manager doesn't work that way](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391))

Is there any way I can render these `uri`s? Any help is appreciated!

(I'm using react-native 0.57.4 btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution was pretty stupid, but all I had to do was set a width and height to the tag, like:

```
<Image style={{width:100,height:100}} source={this.state.pickedImage == null? require('./Placeholder.jpeg'):{uri: this.state.pickedImage}}/>
```

I had initially overlooked this solution because I had done something like:

```
<Image style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}} source={this.state.pickedImage == null? require('./Placeholder.jpeg'):{uri: this.state.pickedImage}}/>
```

and it didn't work at the time but now it works. I have no clue why, but it just works now. If anyone has any idea why, I would be very grateful to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Which 'react-native' version you are using? It doesn't work on all platforms? `require('./image.jpg')` should work, maybe something wrong with your URI.
Or try to load with `Image.resolveAssetSource(source);`

Comment: I'm using react-native 0.57. I don't think there are any bugs of this kind for this version of react, as far as I'm aware. Also, looking it up right now, *as I understand it*, `Image.resolveAssetSource` only seems to convert a path into a uri, which doesn't seem to be much help. (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resolveassetsource)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `res.uri` is not ok.

On my project where I load images from gallery I have `res.node.image.uri` , like this:

```
 <Image style={styles.imageItem}
    source={{ uri: res.node.image.uri }}
 />
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't really work. If the issue was the paths I was using, then I would have hit an error with the `require()` I used above, since I used the *exact* same path when I was initializing `pickedImage` as `require("[PATH]").uri`.

Comment: hmm.. if you `console.log()` the `this.state.pickedImage` what is the output ?